# Drupal 7 - Where can I find templates for render() function?

Tags: drupal, themes

While I was creating my custom template for node, I found out that Drupal adds extra html.

so I changed page.tpl.php like below to test

```
<div style='height:300px'>
  <?php print render($page['content']); ?>
</div>
```

and then changed node.tpl.php to

```
hello
```

the output is:

```
<div style='height:300px'> 
    <div class="region region-content"> 
    <div id="block-system-main" class="block block-system"> 


  <div class="content"> 
    hello  </div> 
</div> 
  </div> 
</div>
```

where do all those extra tags come from?

I actually expected `<div style='height:300px'>hello</div>`

Comment: go to admin->structure->blocks->click 'configure' on the content->choose 'none' for your theme

Comment: You really don't want to do that, that removes the main content completely from your theme. If you do that on the admin theme for example, you will not be able to get it back...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

drupal_render() can be used to render so called renderable arrays. These are self-contained, they tell render() which theme function/template to use.

Try dpm($page['content']), that should then have a '#theme' key that contains that information.

Answer (score 0):

Nice one with the dpm.
To print the h2 and body you could write something like this in the page.tpl.php.

```
<?php print render($page['content']['system_main']['nodes'][1]); ?></div> ?>
```